# Windows Cmd findstr - Regex with digits not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

I'm trying to validate if the IP address argument passed to a batch file is valid or not.
Unfortunately, Windows findstr is not reliably working though the regex fed into is matched.

Following is the summary of all the results.

findstr sets errorlevel to 0 if there is a match, 1 if there is no match.

```
C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo 192.10.10.10 | findstr /R "[0-2][0-9][0-9]\.[0-2][0-9][0-9]\.[0-2][0-9][0-9]\.[0-2][0-9][0-9]"

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo 192.101.101.101 | findstr /R "[0-2][0-9][0-9]\.[0-2][0-9][0-9]\.[0-2][0-9][0-9]\.[0-2][0-9][0-9]"
192.101.101.101

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo %errorlevel%
0

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo 1.1.1.1 | findstr /R "[0-2][0-9][0-9]?\.[0-2]?[0-9][0-9]?\.[0-2]?[0-9][0-9]?\.[0-2]?[0-9][0-9]?"

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo 1.1.1.1 | findstr /R "[0-2]?[0-9][0-9]?\.[0-2]?[0-9][0-9]?\.[0-2]?[0-9][0-9]?\.[0-2]?[0-9][0-9]?"

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo 1.1.1.1 | findstr /R "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo 1.1.1.1 | findstr /b /e /R "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo 1.1.1.1 | findstr /b /e /R "\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b"

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo 1.1.1.1 | findstr /b /e /R "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo 1.1.1.1 | findstr /b /e /R "*\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}*"
FINDSTR: No search strings

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo 1.1.1.1 | findstr /b /e /R "*\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"
FINDSTR: No search strings

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo 1.1.1.1 | findstr /b /e /R "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}*"

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo 1.1.1.1 | findstr /b /e /R "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\>"

C:\iSTEP\VMTicketing\RealVNC>echo %errorlevel%
1
```

[Commandoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vanee.png)

Comment: For info on findstr syntax and limitations, [Please take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman)

Comment: Thank you, but, this doesnt list anything specific to the digit matching limitation, or did I overlook something?

Comment: You've missed something. findstr does not support the regex pattern you are attempting to use.

Comment: @T3RR0R With the findstr, we've /r which supports regex and with this any general regex should be supported (atleast basic digit match) or?

Comment: findstr does not support the regex syntax common to other languages. This fact and the details of the supported syntax are explaind at the link I posted previously.

Comment: Tricky way is  ping-utility usage to check for real name or IP: `ping -n 1 1.1.1.1 -w 1 | (findstr "could not find host" && @echo 1 )||echo 0`

Comment: Thanks for the hint with powershell, initial tests are promising,

Comment: Type `findstr /?` into a Command Prompt window and learn about the supported search expressions…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of performing matches using powershell regex:

```bat
@Echo off
 Call :Regex "131.21.1.101" "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"
 Echo(%Errorlevel%
 Call :Regex "1321.101" "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"
 Echo(%Errorlevel%
Goto :Eof

:Regex
 powershell.exe -noprofile -c "'%~1' -match '%~2'" | findstr /l "True" > nul || Exit /b 1
Exit /b 0
```

For details on powershell regex syntax see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following:

```
echo 1.1.1.1 | findstr "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"
```

It looks like it's working fine, but there are other issues, like a weird value like `isolationlayer_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.479_none_3b8c` also being shown.